# redirecting in a shell script

Tags: unix, replace, sed, sh

I'm trying to write a script to swap out text in a file:

sed s/foo/bar/g myFile.txt > myFile.txt.updated
mv myFile.txt.updated myFile.txt

I evoke the sed program, which swaps out text in myFile.txt and redirects the changed lines of text to a second file. mv then moves .updated txt file to myFile.txt, overwriting it. That command works in the shell.

I wrote:

```
#!/bin/sh
#First, I set up some descriptive variables for the arguments
initialString="$1"
shift
desiredChange="$1"
shift
document="$1"
#Then, I evoke sed on these (more readable) parameters
updatedDocument=`sed s/$initialString/$desiredChange/g $document`
#I want to make sure that was done properly
echo updated document is $updatedDocument
#then I move the output in to the new text document
mv $updatedDocument $document
```

I get the error:

mv: target `myFile.txt' is not a directory

I understand that it thinks my new file's name is the first word of the string that was sed's output. I don't know how to correct that. I've been trying since 7am and every quotation, creating a temporary file to store the output in (disastrous results), IFS...everything so far gives me more and more unhelpful errors. I need to clear my head and I need your help. How can I fix this?

Comment: It seems like you are trying to run the script you wrote with some wild card pattern as your input file. try running with one single file as the file name and see what happens.

Comment: I bet you are fine when you double-quote *all* your variables. Would be useful if you posted all input/arguments and output of your script.

Comment: @user2719058, uh, no, you are not fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try

```
echo $updatedDocument > $document
```

Comment: instead of `echo`, I beliee you meant `cat`. Right ? actually it is better to use `cat $updatedDocument > $document` construct, as this keeps the file's ownership and permissions intact, provided you have read/write access on this file.

Comment: Nope, the output of the sed command is now in the variable updatedDocument. updatedDocument has the contents of the file, not the file name.

Comment: lol what a sleek solution! it works like a charm even with the backticks, of course because it is storing the string in the variable but then echo's output becomes the string and since it's just 'output from a program' the redirect operator works fine with the .txt file.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
updatedDocument=`sed s/$initialString/$desiredChange/g $document`
```

to

```
updatedDocument=${document}.txt
sed s/$initialString/$desiredChange/g $document
```

Backticks will actually put the entire piped output of the sed command into your variable value.

An even faster way would be to not use `updatedDocument` or `mv` at all by doing an in-place `sed`:

```
sed -i s/$initialString/$desiredChange/g $document
```

The -i flag tells sed to do the replacement in-place. This basically means creating a temp file for the output and replacing your original file with the temp file once it is done, pretty much exactly as you are doing.

Comment: hold on, I'm tinkering with it, and thank you so much! (emacs is being slow on this server, one moment)

Comment: My goodness, that was so helpful. Doing it the fast way works! I get a 'redundancy' error? doing it the long way and It's like:

As you had it: mv cannot stat `myFile.txt.txt': No such file or directory. 
After I removed the trailing .txt: 
mv: myFile.txt and myFile.txt are the same file. I'll be studying tonight, trying stuff and figuring out how that messed up. That's the fun part of doing this, and I get the privilege thanks to you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
#First, I set up some descriptive variables for the arguments
echo "$1" | sed #translation of special regex char like . * \ / ? | read -r initialString
echo "$2" | sed 's|[\&/]|\\&|g' | read -r desiredChange
document="$3"

#Then, I evoke sed 
sed "s/${initialString}/${desiredChange}/g" ${document} | tee ${document}
```

don't forget that initialString and desiredChange are pattern interpreted as regex, so a trnaslation is certainly needed
`sed #translation of special regex char like . * \ / ?` is to replace by the correct sed (discuss on several post on the site)

Comment: Thank you, you're very right of course. I wish you had linked to some of those discussions, I've been trying to search for them all day, this website is huge and uses about 50 keywords total! (try searching like input sed unix etc. You never get the result you want)